# if is_bbPress register jquery

Tags: php, customization

i use this code to deregister jquery from wp_head():

```
<?php if ( !is_admin() ) wp_deregister_script('jquery'); wp_head(); ?>
```

i want jquery just added when user on bbpress page, but it's not working:

```
<?php
    if (is_bbPress()) {wp_register_script('jquery'); wp_head();}
    else (!is_admin()) {wp_deregister_script('jquery'); wp_head();}
?>
```

can somebody help me fix this please

Comment: Since BBPress adds thre [CPTs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types) to WP, you should test if the post is one of these types. Wrapping your `wp_register_script` with this: `if(get_post_type() == ‘forum’ OR get_post_type() == ‘topic’ OR get_post_type() == ‘reply’) {` should help. You could limit it further by removing some of the OR declarations.

Comment: can you give me more explanation, i'm newbie

Comment: Where are you adding this code, and why are you de-registering jQuery? Let's take a few steps back, and try to understand what you're really, ultimately trying to accomplish, because you really should never be de-registering jQuery at all in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely out of any context (since it's really not specified in the question), the correct method to *enqueue jQuery only in the context of bbPress* is to add an appropriate conditional inside of a callback, hooked into `wp_enqueue_scripts`. For example, the following would be defined in `functions.php` (i.e. *not* in a template or template-part file):

```
function wpse129696_enqueue_scripts() {
    // Only enqueue jQuery in the context of bbPress
    if ( is_bbpress() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse129696_enqueue_scripts' );
```